# Fedora 22 libinput middle button not work

Tags: fedora, wayland

I used `yum --releasever 22 dirstro-sync` upgrade to Fedora 22 alpha.
I removed a lot of system package by mistake.

My touchpad middle button is not working.

I googled a lot of forums and found this configuration, but it still doesn't work.

```
Section "InputClass"
Identifier "middle button emulation class"
MatchIsPointer "on"
Option "Emulate3Buttons" "on"
EndSection
```

Need help, thanks.

Comment: It looks like X configuration, though you have a Wayland tag. What graphic server do you use?

Comment: @PatJ, thanks for your reply, I do not rember the graphic server. I have been returned back to Fedora 21, all things are fine.

Comment: libinput only supports middle button emulation since version 0.14, and you need xf86-input-libinput 0.10.0 (not yet released at the time of writing this comment). Note that the option name is different to the evdev option name.

http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/driver/xf86-input-libinput/commit/?id=d5fa03c3433637c0fa8cbbfb38dadcf384f06ac3

Answer (score 0):

Having just started using libinput, I also noticed this change - but quickly realised that the middle button emulation I was used to (tapping in the top right corner of the trackpad) is now simply pressing both the left and right button at the same time. This works fine for me.